# change dojox CheckedMultiSelect control default label style

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect control. When I check a few items from the dropdown, the label changed to '2 Item(s) Selected'. How to customize it to something like '2 State(s) Selected'.

```js
var stateCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
    id: 'stateChkMultiSelect',
    dropDown: true,
    multiple: true,
    onChange: lang.hitch(this, function(result){
        stateChecked = result; 
    })
});

stateCheckedMultiSelect.set('style', {width: '100%', height: '30px', fontSize: '14px'});
stateCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label': 'Texas', 'value': 'TX'});
stateCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label': 'New York', 'value': 'NY'});
stateCheckedMultiSelect.startup();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my purpose via codes below. Not sure if there is a better way to do it. If so, please advise.

```js
var StateCheckedMultiSelect = declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {
      startup: function() {
          this.inherited(arguments);  
          setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
              this.dropDownButton.set("label", this.label);          
          }));
      },

      _updateSelection: function() {
          this.inherited(arguments);   
          if(this.dropDown && this.dropDownButton){
              var labels = [];
              array.forEach(this.options, function(option){
                  if(option.selected){
                      labels.push(option.label);
                  }
              });

              this.dropDownButton.set("label", labels.length + 'state(s) selected');
          }
      }
});
```